# Can this PDE be solved through DSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I was trying to solve the linear advection pde, using `DSolve`. I was able to do it using NDSolve, but I was curious to see if Mathematica was able to give the well-know solution of $f(x-ct)$. However, the following code

```
 DSolve[{D[u[x, t], t] + D[u[x, t], x] == 0, u[0, t] == u[2, t], u[x, 0] == Cos[2 \[Pi]*x]}, u[x, t], {x, t}]
```

remains un-evaluated. Is mathematica not able to solve this symbolically, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last bc implies the first.

```
usol[x_, t_] = u[x, t] /. 
       First@DSolve[{D[u[x, t], t] + D[u[x, t], x] == 0, 
    u[x, 0] == Cos[2 \[Pi]*x]}, u, {x, t}]

(*   Cos[2 \[Pi] (-t + x)]   *)

usol[0, t] == usol[2, t] // Simplify

(*   True    *)
```